# Multiple integrals: Double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, self-learning

[image]

For this question, how to evaluate the integral by *changing the order of integration*? Also, how to sketch the region of integration? I really get stuck.

Comment: Can you graph the lines $y = 0$, $y = 1$, $x = 1$, as well as the curve $x = y^{1/3}$, i.e. $y = x^3$?

Comment: Do I need to graph $2πsin(πx^2)/x^2$ as well?

Comment: Please use mathjax instead of images.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Integrate first with respect to $y$, where $y$ goes from $0$ to $x^3$. We end up needing to integrate $2\pi x^2 \sin(\pi x^2)$, an easy substitution.

To get the region, draw $x=y^{1/3}$, or equivalently $y=x^3$. We are integrating over the region in the first quadrant which is below this curve and to the left of the line $x=1$.